# Image upload issue with react-native and PHP(CodeIgniter) as backend

Tags: php, react-native, file-upload, codeigniter-4, react-native-image-picker

I have an app scenario with react native and CodeIgniter as backend.

I have a code snippet to upload image as picked by react-native-image-picker as below:

```
  let formData = new FormData();
  let imageBody = {
                uri: newImage,
                name: 'profilepicture.jpg',
                type: 'image/jpeg',
            };
formData.append('file', (imageBody)) // case 1 gives network error
formData.append('file', JSON.stringify(imageBody)) //case 2 goes OK

 apiUpdateUser(formData)
            .then(res => {

                this.setState({ showSnack: true, snackText: 'Profile Picture Updated'})
            })
            .catch(err => {
                this.setState({ showSnack: true, snackText: 'Update Failed' })
            });
```

The `apiUpdateUser` method goes as :

```
export const apiUpdateUser = body => {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    axios
        .post(ApiRoutes.updateUser, body, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
            }
        })
        .then(res => {
            resolve(res.data);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            reject(Constant.network.networkError);
        });
});
};
```

The Php code at the backend to handle this upload as usual is:

```
$file=$this->request->getFile('file');//in CI
$file=$_FILES['file'];//in normal php
```

My issue is that I do not get anything whatsoever in the `$file` variabe with either of the methods, The file variable is empty in both the cases.

I've checked the implementation in react native and it doesnt seem to be buggy at all comparing with tutorials/demonstrations online. Also the way of handling at the backend is obvious and Ok.

I'm able to achieve this upload with POSTMAN easily but with react-native I'm  facing this error. Can anyone show me some light here??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the `JSON.stringify()` was the culprit line.

Without that line, the app was giving out network error.
That's why I had randomly added it just to see if that was the cause of error.

Since, the network error issue was solved with that addition, I didn't give a second thought about it and only thought it to be a file upload issue. Actually, I now see that this is a known issue of a react native flipper version that I have been using which I managed to solve.

Answer (score 1):

I am using VUE and sending files using Axios. So I think this may help you out.

I am using the following way of form data to set the files or images.

```
formData.append('file', this.form.image_url, this.form.image_url.name);
```

Here this.form.image_url directly refers to the `$event.target.files[0];` where $event targets the input.

In the backend, it is the same as you have it here.

This works out well for me. I am unsure of what you are passing as imageBody so it's hard to comment on that.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
 let imageBody = {
                uri: newImage,
                name: 'profilepicture.jpg',
                type: 'image/jpeg',
            };
apiUpdateUser(imageBody)
            .then(res => {

                this.setState({ showSnack: true, snackText: 'Profile Picture Updated'})
            })
            .catch(err => {
                this.setState({ showSnack: true, snackText: 'Update Failed' })
            });
```

```
export const apiUpdateUser = body => {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    axios
        .post(ApiRoutes.updateUser, body, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        })
        .then(res => {
            resolve(res.data);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            reject(Constant.network.networkError);
        });
});
};
```

Comment: This resulted in the same fate. :(